# SOAP call to a webservice with Talend for ESB and SOAPUI

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui, talend

I query to a webservice with this operation:

```
public schema.cupservices.Output callService(
@WebParam(partName = "inputMessage", name = "inputMessage", targetNamespace = "http://schema/cupServices") schema.cupservices.Input inputMessage);
```

inputMessage is of a type "Input":

```
public abstract class Input {

  @XmlElement(required = true)
  protected LoginData loginData;

  public LoginData getLoginData() {
      return loginData;
  }

  public void setLoginData(LoginData value) {
      this.loginData = value;
  }
}
```

when I try to call the service on Talend using the TSOAP component and with SOAPUI, both take as input:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:cup="http://schema/cupServices">
  <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
       <cup:inputMessage>
       <cup:loginData>
        <cup:username>user</cup:username>
        <cup:password>123</cup:password>
     </cup:loginData>
    </cup:inputMessage>
  </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I get this error:

```
<S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
     <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
 [javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unable to create an instance of schema.cupservices.Input
  - with linked exception:
 [java.lang.InstantiationException]]</faultstring>
```

I know that Input is an abstract class, but the wsdl of the webservice is set in this way...
How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Does LoginData class contain both the elements mentioned in the Soap request.

Comment: yes, contains both username and password